# Trying to Store Json Output as a Variable to pass to dictionary

Tags: python, json

So I am working with an API request from our vulnerability scanner. I want to take a `json` request and pass it to dictionary. That way we can have a user select which 'location' they can pull vulnerabilities from. So my end goal is to take a `json` output, store it so we can sort it. I get this error :

```
TypeError: Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable
```

I think my use of `json.loads` vs `json.dumps` is what is hanging me up.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ApiKey'}


response = requests.get('url', headers=headers)
projects = response.json
print(projects())

#data = response
with open('projects.json','r') as read_file:
     contents = json.loads(read_file)
```

~

Comment: Since you're working with an open file object, use `.load()` instead.  `.loads()` is intended for strings.

Comment: `projects = response.json` --> `projects = response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in how `json.load()` and `json.loads`, most importantly for your case, you'll require `json.load()` because it reads a file to python dictionary while `json.loads` reads a json file to string. So your code should be:

```
with open(url, "r") as read_file:
contents = json.load(read_file)
```